# Higher Moments of a random vector

Tags: probability, random-variables, definition

Let $X = (X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ a random vector. 
I know we can define the variance matrix of $X$ (supposing $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$ ) as
$$\mathbb{E}(XX^{T}), $$
but I'm wondering  what is the a natural way for define higher moments for $X$?

Comment: That is only the covariance matrix if all $\mathbb E[X_i] = 0$.  In general it would be $\mathbb E[(X - \mathbb E[X])(X - \mathbb E[X])^T]$.

Comment: You can construct higher moment tensors.  What would you do with them?  For example third moment tensor {$E(X_iX_jX_k)$}  all i,j,k in [1,n].

Comment: I edited the expression for the covariance matrix, thanks. @herbsteinberg I'm trying to compute an expression like $\mathbb{E}( (Y^Tv)^kY)$ where $v$ is a fixed vector and $Y$ has multivariate normal distribution. I think your comment will help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $m$'th moments of the vector $X$ are $\mathbb E[X^k] = \mathbb E[X_1^{k_1} \ldots X_n^{k_n}]$ where $k_1, \ldots, k_n$ are nonnegative integers with $\sum_i k_i = m$.
These are the components of a tensor: $\mathbb E[X \otimes \ldots \otimes X]$.

Comment: Hello @RobertIsrael is the $k$ exponent a vector $k = (k_1, ..., k_n)$?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Yes it is

Comment: Hi @RobertIsrael is the ⊗ symbol the Kronecker product? If possible can you explicit the argument inside the last expectation please? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product